# How to add summary statistics next to a legend in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, histogram

I have the following simulated data

```
    library(fitdistrplus)
values <- sample(20:50, 100, replace = TRUE)
df <- data.frame(values)
```

and I want to create a histogram as follow

```
create_histogram <- function(data_set, column_name, bins_number) {
  colname     <- as_label(enquo(column_name))
  
  # Calculate summary statistics
  summary_stats <- data.frame(
    mean = mean(data_set[[colname]]),
    max = max(data_set[[colname]]),
    min = min(data_set[[colname]])
  )
  
  ggplot(data_set, aes(x = {{ column_name }})) +
    geom_histogram(aes(y = after_stat(density)), bins = bins_number, fill = "lightblue", colour = "black") +
    stat_function(fun = dnorm , args = list(mean = mean(data_set[[colname]]), sd = sd(data_set[[colname]])),
                  mapping = aes(colour = "Normal")) +
    scale_colour_manual("Distribution", values = c("red")) +
    annotate("text", x = Inf, y = Inf, hjust = 1.1, vjust = 1.1,
             label = paste("Mean:", round(summary_stats$mean, 2), "\nMax:", round(summary_stats$max, 2), "\nMin:", round(summary_stats$min, 2)))
}

create_histogram(df, values, 15)
```

My code works just fine. The result is something like this

[image]

Edited
**My question:** If you paid attention, I am currently showing the summary statistics at the top right of the graph (which in my real project also includes standard deviation, and other statistical summaries). What I like to do, if possible, is to show these summary statistics (mean, max, min, sd, etc) below the legend (outside of the graph) so that my graph is not cramped with information. Is it possible to achieve this in ggplot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this by creating a little text-only plot and insetting it with patchwork. I would probably change the summary stats so that they are a parameter of your function that can be easily changed.

```r
library(patchwork)

create_histogram <- function(data, col, bins, stats = c('mean', 'max', 'min')) {
  
  colname <- deparse(substitute(col))
  
  summary_stats <- do.call('rbind', lapply(stats, \(x)
    data.frame(stat = x, val = do.call(x, list(data[[colname]]))))) |>
    within(y <- seq_along(stats))
  
  p1 <- ggplot(data, aes(x = {{col}})) +
    geom_histogram(aes(y = after_stat(density)), bins = bins, 
                   fill = "lightblue", colour = "black") +
    stat_function(fun = dnorm , args = list(mean = mean(data[[colname]]), 
                                            sd = sd(data[[colname]])),
                  mapping = aes(colour = "Normal")) +
    scale_colour_manual("Distribution", values = c("red")) +
    coord_cartesian(clip = 'off')
  
  p2 <- ggplot(summary_stats, aes(x = 1, y = y)) +
    geom_text(aes(label = paste0(stat, ':')), hjust = 1, size = 3.2) +
    geom_text(aes(label = round(val, 2), x = 1.2), hjust = 0, size = 3.2) +
    annotate('text', label = 'Summary', x = 0, y = length(stats) + 1.1,
             size = 3.8, hjust = 0) +
    xlim(c(0, 2)) +
    theme_void() +
    coord_cartesian(clip = 'off')
  
  p1 + inset_element(p2, 0.85, 0.27, 0.95, 0.42, 'full', clip = FALSE)
}
```

This gives us

```
create_histogram(df, values, 15)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use a tag.

```
library(fitdistrplus)

values <- sample(20:50, 100, replace = TRUE)
df <- data.frame(values)

create_histogram <- function(data_set, column_name, bins_number) {
  colname     <- as_label(enquo(column_name))
  
  # Calculate summary statistics
  summary_stats <- data.frame(
    mean = mean(data_set[[colname]]),
    max = max(data_set[[colname]]),
    min = min(data_set[[colname]])
  )
  
  extra <- paste("Mean:", round(summary_stats$mean, 2), 
                 "\nMax:", round(summary_stats$max, 2), 
                 "\nMin:", round(summary_stats$min, 2))
  ggplot(data_set, aes(x = {{ column_name }})) +
    geom_histogram(aes(y = after_stat(density)), bins = bins_number, fill = "lightblue", colour = "black") +
    stat_function(fun = dnorm , args = list(mean = mean(data_set[[colname]]), sd = sd(data_set[[colname]])),
                  mapping = aes(colour = "Normal")) +
    scale_colour_manual("Distribution", values = c("red")) +
    labs(tag = extra) +
    theme(plot.tag.position = c(1, 0.4),
          plot.tag = element_text(hjust = 1))
}

create_histogram(df, values, 15)
```

[image: tag histogram]

Answer (score 1):

I can get you part of the way there, at least.  In your function, you can make the ggplot without the annotation (I called it `g` below).  Next, you can get the x- and y-axis ranges by calling `gb <- ggplot_build(g)` and pulling the relevant pieces from the layout.  You can then make a `tableGrob()` from the transpose of your summary statistics.  Finally, you can add the table to the figure with `annotation_custom()`.  The piece I don't have a good handle on is how to make sure you're getting the "right" ranges in which to stick the table grob.  This will depend on the size of the plotting window.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(fitdistrplus)
values <- sample(20:50, 100, replace = TRUE)
df <- data.frame(values)
```

```r
create_histogram <- function(data_set, column_name, bins_number) {
  require(gridExtra)
  colname     <- as_label(enquo(column_name))
  weibull_par <- fitdist(data_set[[colname]], "weibull")
  # Calculate summary statistics
  summary_stats <- data.frame(
    mean = mean(data_set[[colname]]),
    max = max(data_set[[colname]]),
    min = min(data_set[[colname]])
  )
  
  g <- ggplot(data_set, aes(x = values)) +
    geom_histogram(aes(y = after_stat(density)), bins = 15, fill = "lightblue", colour = "black") +
    stat_function(fun = dnorm , args = list(mean = mean(data_set[["values"]]), sd = sd(data_set[["values"]])),
                  mapping = aes(colour = "Normal")) +
    stat_function(fun = dweibull, args = list(shape = weibull_par$estimate[[1]], scale = weibull_par$estimate[[2]]),
                  mapping = aes(colour = "Weibull")) +
    scale_colour_manual("Distribution", values = c("red", "blue")) 
  gb <- ggplot_build(g)
  xrg <- gb$layout$panel_params[[1]]$x.range
  yrg <- gb$layout$panel_params[[1]]$y.range
  tgr <- tableGrob(t(summary_stats))
  g +
    annotation_custom(tgr, 
             xmin = xrg[2] , 
             xmax = xrg[2] + .2*diff(xrg), 
             ymin = yrg[1], ymax = yrg[1]+.02) 
}
```

```r
create_histogram(df, values, 15)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-01-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>